# Upload file with Primeng upload component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, primeng

I would upload the file in Angular using [upload component](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/fileupload)

**Here's my HTML:**

```
<p-fileUpload mode="basic" name="demo[]" customUpload="true" accept="image/*" maxFileSize="1000000"  (uploadHandler)="upload($event)"></p-fileUpload>
```

in my **ts** I print param value

```
upload(event) {
  console.log(event)
}
```

I get only metadata and not blob content

```
{"files":[{"objectURL":{"changingThisBreaksApplicationSecurity":"blob:https://prime-ng-file-uploading.stackblitz.io/d429e761-c391-45fa-8628-39b603e25225"}}]}
```

I would also get file content to send via API to the server

[Here's a stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/prime-ng-file-uploading?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the official documentation you have an example:

```
export class FileUploadDemo {
  uploadedFiles: any[] = [];
  constructor(private messageService: MessageService) {}
  onUpload(event) {
    for (let file of event.files) {
      this.uploadedFiles.push(file);
    }
    this.messageService.add({
      severity: 'info',
      summary: 'File Uploaded',
      detail: ''
    });
  }
}
```

When I used `primeNG`, I did it like this (for uploading only 1 file) :

> HTML

```
 <p-fileUpload name="myfile[]" customUpload="true" multiple="multiple" (uploadHandler)="onUpload($event)" accept="application/pdf"></p-fileUpload>
```

> component.ts

```
export class AlteracionFormComponent {
  uplo: File;
  constructor(private fileService: FileUploadClientService) {}
  onUpload(event) {
    for (let file of event.files) {
      this.uplo = file;
    }
    this.uploadFileToActivity();
  }
  uploadFileToActivity() {
    this.fileService.postFile(this.uplo).subscribe(data => {
      alert('Success');
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

And my service (in `Angular`)

> service.ts

```
  postFile(id_alteracion: string, filesToUpload: FileUploadModel[], catalogacion: any): Observable<any> {
    let url = urlAPIAlteraciones + '/';
    url += id_alteracion + '/documentos';

    const formData: FormData = new FormData();

    formData.append('json', JSON.stringify(catalogacion));

    for (let file of filesToUpload) {
      formData.append('documento', file.data, file.data.name);
    }

    console.log(formData);

    let headers = new HttpHeaders();

    return this._http.post(url, formData, { headers: headers });
  }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: can you add please HTML ?

Comment: Yes, I added it

Comment: I have tried your exemple, when I console.log formData after append line, I get empty content. What Am I supposted to have ?

Comment: What do you receive if you log the input parameter in the post method? I update my POST code to the current version I'm using. I log the form and it's empty, but my file travels to bbdd fine

Comment: I have used `formData.get("keyvalue")` to get `formData` content.

Comment: sorry `postFile(this.uplo)` get only one parameter while in your service it needs 3 parameters, I want to know how its work?

Comment: and dear @Aw3same what is in `FileUploadModel` ? also `uplo: File`

Comment: I have this ```export class FileUploadModel {
  data: File;
  type: string;
}```

Answer (score -2):

I'm trying to use the standard PrimeNG approach for uploading multiple files at once.

`<p-fileUpload name="myfile[]" [url]="MyApiUrl" multiple="multiple"></p-fileUpload>`

In my ApiController, I get the following:

```
public List<FileModel> Post()
{
    var files = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
    var result = new List<FileModel>();

    if (files.Count > 0)
    {
        Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UploadFileLocation"], guid.ToString() + "/");
        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["guid"] = guid;

        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path)) { System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path); }

        foreach (string fileName in files.AllKeys)
        {
            var file = files[fileName];
            var filePath = path + file.FileName;
            file.SaveAs(filePath);
            result.Add(_data.InsertFile(FileModel.Create(path, file.FileName)));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The problem I'm having is that "fileName" in `var file = files[fileName]` always equals the first file in the group of files uploaded. I don't know if this is an issue with `HttpContext.Current.Request.Files` or a PrimeNG bug. Has anyone ran into this type of problem?

Doing it this way because I want to store the guid in my session and grab it later on when the form is submitted...

Comment: You asking question in "Answer". It is better to ask as a "Question" - so ppl can answer on it.